# WPF combobox colors

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles

I'm changing the look of all `ComboBox`es in my application by adding this `Style` to App.xaml:

```
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#303030"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#000000"/>
    </Style>
```

There are two colors that I haven't been able to set:

1) the `Background` color when`IsEnabled=false`

2) the highlight `Background` color when the mouse is over the `ComboBox`.

How can I change these two colors?

[edit: it looks like the highlight color is not the same as the mouse over color, because when I move my mouse over the `ComboBox` it will briefly turn the color I defined as the mouse over color, and then turn into some other color (light blue)]

Answer (score 2):

You want to check Style Triggers . Also need to override the ItemContainerStyle to get rid of the default light blue selection color

```
<Style.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="SomeColor" />
  </Trigger>
  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="SomeOtherColor" />
  </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: The highlight doesn't quite work.  I set color Red for IsMouseOver and it does turn red for about a quarter of a second, and then the highlight color turns to light blue (which is used to turn to directly).

Comment: I hope you put this style in to the ItemContainerStyle (Whcih is style for ComboBoxItem)