# Setting combo box foreground color for the disabled state

Tags: wpf, combobox, triggers, styling

I want to change color of combo box for diasbled state to more darker one. 
Please let me know how do achieve this using triggers or any other way. Thanks !!

Comment: There is the answer you are looking for:)
[stackoverflow thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388833/wpf-combobox-background-color-when-disabled

Comment: All controls look alike when they are disabled.How can you set color to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the color in a simple property trigger:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: combobox corners changed to rounded one after applying above trigger.. HOw to change shape of combox to flat one?

Comment: Background or foreground color? Question asks for foreground, answer uses background. This indeed wouldn't work for changing foreground.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>            
    </Trigger>
```

In my case I set 
**DyanmicResource** to **SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey**

You can set according to your requirement Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx) out